# How do I verbalize the term F[_] in scala/cats-effect

Tags: scala, cats-effect, http4s

I'm learning the concept of F[_] as a constructor for other types, but how do you pronounce this to another human or say it in your head (for us internal monologue thinkers).

Similar to how `x => x + 1` has an official verbalization of "x **goes to** x plus one", how does my internal monologue parse `def stream[F[_]: Async]: Stream[F, Nothing] = ...`?

Edit: I've taken to calling it "Flunderscore" but I'm legit worried that if I keep doing this I'm going to screw up and say this in a professional context.  Plz help.

Comment: It is just an special use case of a kind with one type paramter. Also professionally, just calling it `F` is totally fine.

Comment: When in the context of cats-effect I just call it the "effect" type

Comment: Usually F type, or higher kinded type of F if you wanna mention the higher kind. If you wanna go mathematical, I sometimes call it F domain

Comment: You can call it a *type constructor*. The same way a constructor constructs a class, a type constructor, given a type parameter, constructs a type.

Comment: Usually, I would use the word _"effect"_ or _"program"_ for the `F[_]` and _"capability"_ for the evidence. Thus, I would say: `stream` is a method parametric in any effect type `F[_]` as long as there exists the capability `Async` for such type, and it will return a `Stream[F, Nothing]`

Comment: FWIW I don't think I've ever heard "x goes to ..." either. But I'm not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking that's an effect or program, but I found program to be more understandable when explained out of the context of FP; in a functional way of thinking, we can consider every value as a program, and every program as value, so We can think of it in terms of programs that create programs.

for instance:

1. the following is a program that for any program type F, takes an integer and creates a F program that outputs an integer

```scala
def foo[F[_]](i: Int): F[Int] = ???
```

which is an absurd program (can't be implemented)

2. the following is another program, that for any program type F that can be composed sequentially, takes an integer and returns a F program that outputs an integer

```scala
def bar[F[_]: Monad](i: Int): F[Int] = ???
```

Note that types like `List[T]` and other containers are also programs, that output a sequence of values.